# Resolving Implicits in Multiple Extended Traits

Tags: scala, implicit

Let's say I have 3 traits.

```
scala> trait A { implicit val a = "A" }
defined trait A

scala> trait B { implicit val b = "B" }
defined trait B

scala> trait C { implicit val c = "C" }
defined trait C
```

Then, `Z` extends all 3 of them.

```
scala> class Z extends A with B with C {
     |   def foo(implicit x: String) = println(x)
     | }
defined class Z
```

Create an instance.

```
scala> new Z
res0: Z = Z@39a12a0e
```

But, why can't an `implicit String` be resolved? Looks like there are potentially 3 of them (inside of the traits).

```
scala> res0.foo
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter x: String
              res0.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

implicit method parameters are resolved in a number of places. You should put your implicits in the class companion object or in the scope where you're making the call (thanks to Travis Brown for the comment). Even if you had a single class with an implicit val and the "foo" method, you would have the same result.

You could use default arguments:

```
def foo(x:String="A")
```

or do something similar to what you want with stackable traits:

```
  trait Foo { def foo(x: String): Unit }

  trait A extends Foo {
    abstract override def foo(x: String = "A") = super.foo(x)
  }

  trait B extends Foo {
    abstract override def foo(x: String = "B") = super.foo(x)
  }

  trait C extends Foo {
    abstract override def foo(x: String = "C") = super.foo(x)
  }

  trait Z extends Foo {
    override def foo(x: String = "default") = println(x)
  }

  class ZImplA extends Z with A
  new ZImplA().foo() // this prints "A"

  class ZImplB extends Z with A with B
  new ZImplB().foo() // this prints "B"
```

Comment: This is potentially a little misleading—when looking for an implicit `T`, Scala will look all kinds of places beyond "the scope in which you are making the call"—including `T`'s companion object (if any), etc. It's just not going to look inside `Z` in this case.

Comment: you are perfectly right, sorry if I've been too hasty. There are a number of questions on SO on implicit resolution, it's a complex matter

Comment: In my example, why can't `Z.foo` find an `implicit String`? If I'm reading Scala in Depth's section on implicit resolution correctly, then `Z` should find an implicit. `Definitions and declarations that are local, inherited, or made available by a package clause in the same source file where the definition occurs have highest precedence.`)

Comment: your implicits are neither local, inherited or made available by a package clause. They are not local because they are not in the scope of the "z.foo" call (the repl scope, the same where "res0" is defined), they are not inherited because you are not calling "foo" in a subclass of Z (same reason)